# scrapy spider code not running because of syntax?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, syntax-error

so my projects seem to keep failing for the same reason. I get syntax error. I'm using anaconda and visual code studio, I have the environment setup correctly, i think*.

The code i'm using is the following:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class BestMoviesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'best_movies'
    allowed_domains = ['imdb.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/chart/top']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//td[@class='titleColumn']/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
       yield {
           'title': response.xpath("//h1/text()").get(),      
            'year': response.xpath("//li[@class="ipc-inline-list__item"]/span/text()").get(),    
           'duration': response.xpath("(//li[@class="ipc-inline-list__item"])[3]/text()").get(),     
           'genre': response.xpath("//span[@class="ipc-chip__text"]/text()").get(),     
           'rating': response.xpath("//span[@class="AggregateRatingButton__RatingScore-sc-1ll29m0-1 iTLWoV"]/text()").get(),     
           'movie_url': response.url,     
       }
```

The error I'm getting is : **line 18
'year': response.xpath("//li[@class="ipc-inline-list__item"]/span/text()").get(),
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Also, I have 2 errors on VSC regarding { and ( not being closed but I think that's because my code isn't running.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have double quotes in your XPath and then again you are using double quotes to surround the entire XPath.

Python interpreter and your VSCode linter can't figure out where your string is beginning and where it is ending.

If your XPath has `"` the use `'` to surround the entire XPath, or the other way round.

Change this from:

```
'year': response.xpath("//li[@class="ipc-inline-list__item"]/span/text()").get(),
```

to:

```
'year': response.xpath('//li[@class="ipc-inline-list__item"]/span/text()').get(),
```

Here is your entire parse_item fixed:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    yield {
        'title': response.xpath("//h1/text()").get(),
        'year': response.xpath('//li[@class="ipc-inline-list__item"]/span/text()').get(),
        'duration': response.xpath('(//li[@class="ipc-inline-list__item"])[3]/text()').get(),
        'genre': response.xpath('//span[@class="ipc-chip__text"]/text()').get(),
        'rating': response.xpath('//span[@class="AggregateRatingButton__RatingScore-sc-1ll29m0-1 iTLWoV"]/text()').get(),
        'movie_url': response.url,
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I understood everything, how nice of you! Hope you have an excellent day!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the string definition of the xpaths.

You can just use single quotes and you should be fine:

```
# not
'year': response.xpath("//li[@class="ipc-inline-list__item"]/span/text()").get(),

# Instead use
'year': response.xpath('//li[@class="ipc-inline-list__item"]/span/text()').get(),
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem of quotes:

Try to replace `year: response.xpath("//li[@class="ipc-inline-list__item"]/span/text()").get()`

by `year: response.xpath('//li[@class="ipc-inline-list__item"]/span/text()').get()`

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Much appreciated! :D